# Getting arraylist of json

Tags: php, json

I have the following Json

```
[response] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => 1
        [httpStatus] => 200
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 230
                [1] => 1956
                [2] => 1958
                [3] => 2294
   )
```

How do i get the data array out of the response?

I know this is quite simple.

**update**

Here is some of my source code

```
$url = $base . http_build_query( $params );
$result = file_get_contents( $url );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( json_decode( $result ) );
echo '</pre>';
$data = $result->response->data;
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not JSON, that is a PHP array or object. You didn't provide enough info to tell which one it is.

You can access the data array from it using either:

```
$data = $arr['response']->data;
```

Or:

```
$data = $obj->response->data;
```

Replace `$arr` or `$obj` with the actual variable name.

**Edit**

Your variable contains a string, because after decoding it you did not save the result. Try the following code:

```
$url = $base . http_build_query( $params );
$json = file_get_contents( $url );

$result = json_decode($json);
$data = $result->response->data;

echo '<pre>',print_r($data, true),'</pre>';
```

Comment: when i try this:     $data = $result['response']->data;
    print_r($data);
}
my console writes a blank line

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Try the object version: `$data = $result->response->data; print_r($data);`

Comment: Same thing happens :S

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Oh I see, you are not storing the decoded result. You need to do something like `$result = json_decode($result);` otherwise you just throw out the decoded object and `$result` still contains the original JSON string you got from `file_get_contents`.

Comment: That fixed it THANK YOU all of you for your responses

Answer (score 2):

```
$json_object = json_decode($result);
print_r($json_object->response->data);
```

In PHP, `->` is the *object operator* (or *arrow*). I'd encourage you to read more about [Objects in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).

Comment: can i use the same to return it as an array? like return $json_object->response->data

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Yes. `$json_object->response->data` is just a variable reference, so you can do anything to it that you could do with a variable - print it, return it, change it, whatever.

Comment: when i try this i get  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Note my assumption. What's the variable that stores the JSON?

Comment: From your edit, seems like you never store the decoded JSON. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

simply like this :-

```
[response] => stdClass Object
    (
        [status] => 1
        [httpStatus] => 200
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => 230
                [1] => 1956
                [2] => 1958
                [3] => 2294
   )
$json_data=json_decode($response,true);
```